# Enabling RequiredFieldValidator From Code Behind

Tags: asp.net, css, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I'm displaying an error message for the requiredfieldvalidator from code behind but the display is set to none or visible is hidden. I tried to do .visible = true but it's still hidden. How can I make it to show the error message? The textbox is inside a GridView.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SSN">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSSN" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSSN" />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

TextBox txtSSN = (TextBox)r.FindControl("txtSSN");
if (txtSSN.Text == "")
        {
      RequiredFieldValidator RequiredFieldValidator1 = (RequiredFieldValidator)r.FindControl("RequiredFieldValidator1");
      RequiredFieldValidator1.Visible = true;
      RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = true;
      RequiredFieldValidator1.ErrorMessage = "This field is required.";
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the [`IsValid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.isvalid%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property to `false`.

```
RequiredFieldValidator1.IsValid = false;
```

You shouldn't need to bother with the visibility, this will happen automatically.

Answer (score 4):

A validator shows itself when validation was invalid, so trigger it via [`Validator.Validate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
RequiredFieldValidator1.Validate();
```

> Performs validation on the associated input control and updates the IsValid property.

Answer (score 0):

The field must not be in a grid to use `Isvalid`. 
 If it's in grid use `page.validate()` and check `page.isvalid()`.